# how programming this whidget in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

recently I work work on wordpress template and edit that . I add some block manually to that , now I want convert my code to widget . I want add 4image and link to seems like that . what can I do for this ?

[image: this is my template]

Answer (score 0):

Create A wordpress widget, add your code which to be displayed into the public area. ( public function)